# Unable to bond two Wi-Fi adapters

Tags: linux, networking, routing, opensuse, bonding

I have two mobile Wi-Fi routers (with IP *192.168.0.1* and *192.168.1.1*) and two usb Wi-Fi adapters and trying to bond them into failover connection. Using *OpenSUSE 12.3* in YaST I've chosen *Traditional Method with ifup* and first of all I've created two DHCP connections
[image: different Wi-Fi connections]

With following routes it works well (with network access and both admin interfaces available on *192.168.0.1* and *192.168.1.1*) but without bonding

```
sudo /sbin/route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0

sudo /sbin/ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:43639 (42.6 Kb)  TX bytes:43639 (42.6 Kb)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:DD:A9:2D:53:92  
          inet addr:192.168.1.107  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::16dd:a9ff:fe2d:5392/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9640939 (9.1 Mb)  TX bytes:3377293 (3.2 Mb)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AC:22:0B:92:CE:13  
          inet addr:192.168.0.159  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ae22:bff:fe92:ce13/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20869 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3655149 (3.4 Mb)  TX bytes:3807217 (3.6 Mb)
```

Now I'm trying to add bond connection like in [this](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Bonding) manual
[image: DHCP bond]

[image: Bond slaves]

[image: active-backup]

```
sudo /sbin/route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0

sudo /sbin/ifconfig
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:DD:A9:2D:53:92  
          inet addr:192.168.0.159  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::16dd:a9ff:fe2d:5392/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:773 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:854 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:181197 (176.9 Kb)  TX bytes:173550 (169.4 Kb)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:946 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:90497 (88.3 Kb)  TX bytes:90497 (88.3 Kb)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:DD:A9:2D:53:92  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1026 (1.0 Kb)  TX bytes:288 (288.0 b)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:DD:A9:2D:53:92  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:852 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:180171 (175.9 Kb)  TX bytes:173262 (169.2 Kb)

cat /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-bond0
BONDING_MASTER='yes'
BONDING_MODULE_OPTS='mode=active-backup miimon=100'
BONDING_SLAVE0='wlan0'
BONDING_SLAVE1='wlan1'
BOOTPROTO='dhcp'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR=''
MTU=''
NAME=''
NETMASK=''
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
USERCONTROL='no'
```

Now I'm faced with two problems:

1. I cannot access admin panel on 192.168.1.1
2. Connections does not ensure each other

a) with first adapter disconnected

```
sudo /usr/sbin/traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.122.193), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets using UDP
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.984 ms   0.977 ms   0.970 ms
 ...
```

b) and with other one disconnected there is no connection at all

```
sudo /usr/sbin/traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.122.193), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets using UDP
 1  * * *
 ...
 30  * * *
```

Comment: Does 192.168.0.1 → 192.168.1.1 ping work? According to your routing table, the host can't reach 1.1 itself so it'll send packets through 0.1

Comment: @CijcoSistems No it doesn't. Wi-Fi routers (ZTE MF910 & Huawei E5776) are not customized to be accessible for each other and I'm afraid they couldn't be.

Comment: Since they are in different networks, I would suggest you take a different approach than joining wlan0 and wlan1. Furthermore, they probably are in different WLANs (are they?) so bonding them at link layer will force them to choose one WLAN. You could try to joining one WLAN with each interface instead. This way you'd have 2 working IPs and "all you have to do" is [load balance](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com.es/2008/09/opensource-load-balancing-software.html) traffic between them. I hope this can both increase your available bandwidth and provide failover connection.

Comment: @CijcoSistems Thank your for response. Probably I'll follow your suggestion after all. I'm afraid only `"all you have to do"` part, maybe there are more easy steps to set up something like load balance using routes without configuring additional software.

Answer (score 0):

Most wifi devices use MAC filtering, where they will not send a frame where the source MAC address is not their own MAC address.

Most bonding modes change the device's MAC address by design. All bonding modes will run into situations where they may send frames with a different MAC.

Either don't do this, or get wifi devices which don't filter like this.

The network security community probably have a list of wifi devices which are suitable for this, those devices are often used for wardriving and for spoofing another device to take over a wifi channel. Search around.